# netplan using wrong backends

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan, ip, systemd-networkd

### Background

I have a `netplan` `.yaml` configuration file in `/etc/netplan/`. The first few lines are as follows:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
# ...and so it continues...
```

When I run the command `sudo netplan --debug generate`, I get an output ending with `NetworkManager: definition <ethernet_name> is not for us (backend 1)`. This didn't look like it worked properly, but anyway I tried running `sudo netplan --debug apply`, it printed some debug statements, didn't look like it failed, but then when I ran `ip addr`, the changes specified in the `.yaml` file were not reflected in my ethernet name, IP address etc.

Okay, I tried changing the `yaml` file so that the `renderer` line read `renderer: NetworkManager`. I reran `sudo netplan --debug generate`, this time I get an output ending in `networkd: definition <ethernet_name> is not for us (backend 2)`. When I then run `sudo netplan --debug apply`, I get an error `Failed to start NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service not found.` followed by a Python traceback.

It seems like whichever of the 2 renderers I specify in the `yaml` file, `netplan` tries to use the other one (*or* possibly it is failing silently in a different way that I'm not aware of).

### Question

How do I make `netplan` use the correct backend that I specify in the `.yaml` file?

(Also, for bonus points, what does the "renderer" actually do in `netplan`?)

### Updates

- As per https://netplan.io/troubleshooting/ , I have checked the `.link` and `.network` files in `/run/systemd/network/` after running `generate` with the original `renderer: networkd`, and the details (name, set-name, MAC address etc) match what I put in the `.yaml` file. Maybe `netplan generate` is working properly after all, and the issue is somewhere else...

Comment: We would need to look at all your configs and your YAML files in /etc/netplan/ to determine where the config is going screwy

Comment: @ThomasWard `NetworkManger`  is one ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Ahhh, yes it's trying to use NetworkManager.  THey want to NOT use network manager, so they need to remove wherever NetworkManager is the renderer if they want to use networkd as normal.  But I think the problem is that it's not paying attention to backends proper, NetworkManager or otherwise, hence it would STILL be beneficial to see all the yamls that Netplan is parsing

Comment: The message "not for us" means what it says: it is a debug message saying that the backend is NOT being considered for the interface in question.  Unfortunately you don't get a message confirming that it IS for the other backend.

Comment: @slangasek you are right, it turns out that `NetworkManager: definition <ethernet_name> is not for us (backend 1)` does *not* imply that `networkd` is not being used, as I had wrongly assumed. I was able to confirm this by looking at the `.link` and `.network` files in `/run/systemd/network/` after running `generate` with the original `renderer: networkd`, as I mentioned under "Updates" above. I was also eventually able to fix the problem (see my answer below), although I'm still not 100% sure what I did wrong in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `netplan` was using the correct backend (`networkd`). When the debug message was printed saying `NetworkManager: definition <ethernet_name> is not for us (backend 1)`, I wrongly interpreted this as thinking that `netplan` was trying and failing to use `NetworkManager` and then giving up, whereas in fact, it was using `networkd` (as confirmed by looking at the generated files in `/run/systemd/network/`, as mentioned under "Updates" in my original question).

I was just confused because I thought the message about `NetworkManager` was implying that `networkd` was not being used, whereas this was not the case.

Eventually I got the whole thing working by trying different combinations of hardware connections and removing extra unnecessary `.yaml` files. I don't think there was anything wrong with the setup I described above, I was just thrown off by the error message, thinking that `netplan` was trying to use the wrong backend, when it was in fact using the correct backend.

Answer (score 2):

The renderer key tells netplan what backend to use. The options are `networkd`, `NetworkManager`, and `sriov`.

You have an example that does not match the errors you show: you have `renderer: networkd` in your yaml. So what is `NetworkManger` supposed to be in your notices? That is an invalid backend as it is missing an "a". Plus not what you have in your yaml.

If you want NetworkManager to handle the configuration of the connection your file should have *only* this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, the `NetworkManger` (missing an "a") was just a typo from me at the start of my answer, that propagated when I copied and pasted it in the rest of my answer. Normally I would have just copied and pasted the original error message, but the network configuration I'm trying to set up is in a virtual machine in VMWare Workstation which doesn't (to my knowledge) support using a mouse, or copy and pasting.

Comment: Also, I do want to use `networkd` as the backend (well, not "want" exactly, but this is specified in some more general instructions that I'm trying to follow).